# python3 self variable from class to decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I'm trying to build my first decorator and implement it in a class.

```
# decorator class
class Cache(object):
  def __init__(self,filename,**kwargs):
    self.time_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(**kwargs)
    self.filename = filename

  def __call__(self,fn):
    if not os.path.isfile(self.filename):
      return self.cache(fn(self))

    time_ago = self.time_ago
    filename = self.filename
    c_age = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(filename))
    m_age = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(filename))
    print (c_age)
    print (m_age)
    print (time_ago)
    if c_age < time_ago or m_age < time_ago:
      return self.cache(fn(self))
    else:
      return self.read()

  def cache(self,data):
      with open(self.filename,'r+') as ef:
        ef.write(data)
        return ef.read()

  def read(self):
    f = open(self.filename,'r')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    return data
```

I'm trying to call the decorator in the below class:

```
class Zabb(object):

  @Cache('nodes.json',minutes=1)
  def getNodes(self):
    return "Get Nodes"
```

I call it like this:

```
z = Zabb()
nodes = z.getNodes()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./deco.py", line 52, in <module>
nodes = z.getNodes()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I'm close to making this work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `__call__` needs to return a higher order function (wrapped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a higher-order-function *(wrapped)* from the `__call__` method. Add an inner method and return it.

```
def __call__(self, fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs): # <-- Add this wrapper
        if not os.path.isfile(self.filename):
            return self.cache(fn(*args, **kwargs))

        time_ago = self.time_ago
        filename = self.filename
        c_age = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(filename))
        m_age = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(filename))
        print (c_age)
        print (m_age)
        print (time_ago)
        if c_age < time_ago or m_age < time_ago:
            return self.cache(fn(*args, **kwargs))
        else:
            return self.read()
    return wrapper # <-- Return the wrapper
```

Answer (score 1):

Decorators are easier to understand if you forget the `@deco` syntactic sugar and reason on what it *really* do. In your example,

```
@Cache('nodes.json',minutes=1)
def getNodes(self):
    return "Get Nodes"
```

really means :

```
def getNodes(self):
    return "Get Nodes"

getNodes = Cache('nodes.json',minutes=1)(getNodes)
```

which actually rebinds `Zabb.getNodes` to the result of `Cache('nodes.json',minutes=1).__call__(getNodes)` - which is a string, not a function.

What you want is to make `Cache.__call__` return a function that will wrap the call the decorated function, ie:

```
  def __call__(self,fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
      if not os.path.isfile(self.filename):
        return self.cache(fn(self))

      time_ago = self.time_ago
      filename = self.filename
      c_age = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(filename))
      m_age = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(filename))
      print (c_age)
      print (m_age)
      print (time_ago)
      if c_age < time_ago or m_age < time_ago:
        return self.cache(fn(self))
      else:
        return self.read()
    return wrapper
```